# How to extract values from json array

Tags: android

Hi i am new to the android development,i want to extract values from json array can you please guide me.

Here is my json

```
[
    {
        "Id": "c0f3310b-5ec2-4af0",
        "UserId": "fd83ca17-41f5-472a",
        "ProfileId": "100006690",
        "ProfileType": "facebook",
        "ProfileDate": "/Date(1380894956000)/",
        "ProfileStatus": 1
    },
    {
        "Id": "6954433d-b78e-47b6",
        "UserId": "fd83ca17-41f5-8efe",
        "ProfileId": "100004492",
        "ProfileDate": "/Date(1380894685000)/",
        "ProfileStatus": 1,
        "ProfileType": "facebook"
    }
]
```

Thank you

Comment: post what you have tried

Comment: try to search existing thread like this then if u can't find any that's the time to post it here. cause I think there's already lot's of thread about this one that can help you solve your problem.-

Comment: [Check How to search in google ?](http://bit.ly/17hmgKC)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like below coding

```
JSONArray jObject = new JSONArray(jsoninputstring);
        for (int i = 0; i < jObject.length(); i++) {
             JSONObject obj = jObject.getJSONObject(i);

             String name= obj.getString("Id");
             String email= obj.getString("UserId");
             String image= obj.getString("ProfileId");
        }
```

Here is the tutorial for JSON parsing

http://lakyrana.blogspot.in/

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

http://androidexample.com/JSON_Parsing_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=71&aaid=95

Comment: links can be posted as comments. post some details

Comment: @Raghunandan Yup Posted

Answer (score 0):

Create new JSONArray object and iterate over it.

```
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(jsonString);
for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
   JSONObject obj = arr.getJSONObject(i);
   // read data from obj using obj.getString method.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   JSONArray categories = responseData.getJSONArray("categories"); // your JSON array
   for(int i=0; i < categories.length(); i++){
        JSONObject ob = (JSONObject) categories.get(i);
        ob.getString("Id");
        ob.getString("UserId"); // and so on
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest you to check out JacksonParser... You can download jar files from [this link](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonDownload) and you can easily find so much example how to use it. It is the easiest and fastest way to parse json into object.

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(yourResponseString);
for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){

         JSONObject dataObject=dataArray.getJSONObject(i);

            String ID=dataObject.getString("Id");
            String UserID=dataObject.getString("UserId");
            String ProfileID = jsonObject.getString("ProfileId");
               ..
}
```